# Knockoutjs mappings don't add observables to array of strings

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm getting this kind of data from the server

```
{
    FirmName: "Firm Name",
    Address: "123 Address",
    AltNames: [
        "First Alt Name",
      "Second Alt Name"
    ]
  }
```

I'm using knockout mappings plugin to map the  data to a viewModel with ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

However, anytime I change any string array element, my changes are not propagated to the viewModel. What do I do to fix the problem?

My js:

```
function firmModel() {
    //this is what I get from the server
  var data = {
    FirmName: "Firm Name",
    Address: "123 Address",
    AltNames: [
        "First Alt Name",
      "Second Alt Name"
    ]
  };
  
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
  
}

var em = new firmModel();
ko.applyBindings(firmModel);
```

My html:

```
<div>
  <label>Company</label>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: FirmName">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Address</label>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: Address">
</div>
<br>
<h3>
Alt Names
</h3>
<ul data-bind="foreach: AltNames">
  <li>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data">
  </li>
</ul>

<br/><br/>
<h2>
Result of the changes where I see whether viewModel picks up my changes above
</h2> 
<span>Company: </span><span data-bind="text: FirmName"></span><br/>
<span>Address: </span><span data-bind="text: Address"></span><br/>
<br/>
Alt Names: <br/>
<ul data-bind="foreach: AltNames">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n87esdLv/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `foreach` you can't use `$data`:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: $data">
```

as you can read in [documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html):

> $rawData
>
> This is the raw view model value in the current context. Usually this will be the same as $data, but **if the view model provided to Knockout is wrapped in an observable, $data will be the unwrapped view model**, and ***$rawData will be the observable itself***.

Then, you need to use `$rawData` instead, because the content of the `AltNames` array must be observables, not strings.

The strings in the `AltNames` must be observables.  You need to customize the creation of the `AltNames` array with [custom object construction using “create”](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html):

```
var mapping = {
        'AltNames': {
                create: function(options) {
                        return ko.observable(options.data);
                }
        }
}

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);
```

This is a runnable example:

```js
function firmModel() {
    //this is what I get from the server
  var data = {
    FirmName: "Firm Name",
    Address: "123 Address",
    AltNames: [
        "First Alt Name",
      "Second Alt Name"
    ]
  };
  
  //ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
    var mapping = {
            'AltNames': {
                    create: function(options) {
                            return ko.observable(options.data);
                    }
            }
    }

  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);       
  
}

var em = new firmModel();
ko.applyBindings(firmModel);
```

```css
h2{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Company</label>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: FirmName">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Address</label>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: Address">
</div>
<br>
<h3>
Alt Names
</h3>
<ul data-bind="foreach: AltNames">
  <li>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $rawData">
  </li>
</ul>

<br/><br/>
<h2>
Result of the changes
</h2> 
<span>Company: </span><span data-bind="text: FirmName"></span><br/>
<span>Address: </span><span data-bind="text: Address"></span><br/>
<br/>
Alt Names: <br/>
<ul data-bind="foreach: AltNames">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Jose, thank you so much! I've got a follow up question. What if AltNames is not a root element. For example, ` {FirmNames: {MainName: "Bla", AltNames: ["One", "Two]}} `? I've tried using ` "FirmNames.AltNames": {
                    create: function(options) {
                            return ko.observable(options.data);
                    }
                } ` but it didn't work

Comment: Can you change this array of strings to an array of objects:  `{FirmNames: {MainName: "Bla", AltNames: [{name:"One"},{name: "Two}]}}`  Then, the plugin will do the job without the need of the `mapping`.  I add `name:` in `AltNames`.

Comment: In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b2L3nmc5/3/ I use the same `mapping` and I think it works.

Comment: Thank you, Jose! You're right. I needed to use $rawData instead of $data in ko loop. Thanks again!